# Clicking button in listview doesn't work

Tags: java, android

Having knowledge that similar cases were reported and there are many answers to this topic, unfortunately anything works in my case.
Here is my code from activity:

```
listViewOfReastaurants = findViewById(R.id.listViewOfSensors);
        listViewOfReastaurants.setDividerHeight(10);
        listOfRestaurants = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_button, listOfRestaurants);
        listViewOfReastaurants.setAdapter(adapter);

        listViewOfReastaurants.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        DishOfTheDay.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
```

Here is my layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="8dp">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewOfSensors"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

And row template:

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/Row"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
android:textSize="15sp"
android:padding="20dp"
android:focusable="false">
```

Unfortunately clicking button doesnt take any effect. I tried with setting parameters like focusable etc. but nothing helped.

Comment: It seems: listOfRestaurants is an empty array, how did you update its value?

Comment: It will not work and this is normal behavior. You are setting click listener on each row item of list view. So the listener is only applicable for row view only. But you clicked on a button view. Though its seems like here the button is the only item in each row. But here the click listener of button overrides your custom click listener. Hope you understood. :)

Comment: @Cao, if the list was empty then he might not see any item(here button) in list view and also not able click on those buttons.

Answer (score 2):

I think by using `context` of the class you can switch between activities.

**Try something like:**

```
  listViewOfReastaurants.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        DishOfTheDay.class);
                Context context=getBaseContext();
                context.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
```

I hope this one will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are sending empty **listOfRestaurants**.
And the answer for your solution, try to change **Button** type **TextView** and remove *focusable* attribute.